# What is Initialization Function in so file?

Tags: shared-libraries, init, ida

I am seeing some so file in IDA
by the way I saw some word that "ELF Initialization Function table" in IDA-View

so my question is what is Initalization Function?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

[ELF](https://www.cs.stevens.edu/%7Ejschauma/631A/elf.html)

Pointers to functions which will be executed when program starts

Comment: Please extend your answer a little bit, e.g. by quoting relevant entries from the link as most likely the link will be dead soon and then your answer will be a little bit too short to be helpful for someone who has the same question.